# android-java how to cancel an asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask that performs an HttpPost request, I have a field were people put their email in and also have a method that checks for correct email. What I would like to do is cancel my AsyncTask if the email verification comes out to false. I have tried several things and nothing works this is my code..

```
//check if email is valid
public  boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    boolean isValid = false;

    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// AsyncTask

private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    String email;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
       Email= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
       email= Email.getText().toString().trim();

        if(isEmailValid(email)== false){
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"Not a valid Email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // I would like to cancel Async here and return but this is a type Void
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       // HttpPost stuff here I return a type String
    }

   // @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_uri) {
      // post stuff
    }
}
```

My **onPreExecute()** is of type void, I tried changing it to type Boolean but I get a mismatch on incompatible type. My doinBackground has to have type String because I am returning something to the **onPostExecute**. I simply want to abort the AsyncTask if the email returns false any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IMO you should check it before running `asyncTask`**, but if you want it your way - you could set some global variable to `false` and return it, then in `doInBackground` method check this variable and return it to `onPostExecute`.

One of many possibilities:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
       String email;
       boolean emailValid = true;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();

           Email= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
           email= Email.getText().toString().trim();


           if(!isEmailValid(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"Not a valid Email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                emailValid = false;

                return;
           }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
           if(emailValid) {
               // now you know it isn't valid
               return "invalid";
           }
        }

       // @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_uri) {
            if(file_uri.equals("invalid") {
                // now you know it isn't valid event here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just did as you suggested checked it on the Onclick and was able to catch it before Async started thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can't cancel the `AsyncTask`, even if you call `cancel(true)`. The thread will continue running in background, but doesn't return a result. I already made my own experiment in one month to cancel it. But, nothing can stop its thread and made me stress. So I decided to move to `IntentService`.

Since `AsyncTask` is only for single task in with short time, it's better than using `IntentService` which purposed for long running task. But, I recommend you to use `IntentService` or `Service` if you want to stop the task included with its own thread.